# IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename: "C:/Users/...../file.csv"

Tags: python, csv, rawstring

I'm running a simulation in which I'm reading and writing multiple files (both .txt or .csv) at each timestep in order to communicate with external programs in C#.

Every so often in the simulation, I have the error: 
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename:"C:/Users/..../filename.csv"

It doesn't happen every time I run it, and if I run each line manually it sometimes works just fine but sometimes not.

I'm writing the .csv's like this:

```
path=r'C:/Users/..../filename.csv'
datatowrite.to_csv(path, index=False)
```

and the .txt files like this:

```
    path=r'C:/Users/.../Filename.txt'
    np.savetxt(path, datatowrite)
```

I looked at similar questions but most have to do with use of backslashes and colons so I use raw strings and forward slashes throughout my code and I turn the string into a variable "path" before each time I save or access a file. When I run the simulation it will work sometimes, and other times I get an error:

```
[Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename: 'C:/Users/.../Filename.txt'
```

I should note that I am writing and saving files on Dropbox - could this be the issue? Perhaps the files are not syncing fast enough before the next line tries to access them. Regardless, I don't understand why it works sometimes and doesn't work other times. Any suggestions?

Comment: It could be that dropbox locks the files and you can't access them.

Comment: Saved all files in the desktop and so far so good. I guess I'll sync to dropbox once daily instead of real-time. Thanks for the help.